# Any solutions to a black screen on a nikon d3500

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, brightness, lcd

My husband bought me a nikon d3500 last year. To summarize the lcd screen went black a couple months later. While troubleshooting online I was able to shine a light on it and could see the screen it was just very dim.

I sent the camera to nikon but they can't fix it because its not a usa camera.

My husband replaced the lcd screen and it still won't work.

It takes pictures and I am able to access the settings to reset the camera but nothing I do will make the screen brighter.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the backlight of the screen is broken. When you say your husband replaced the lcd screen .. does the replacement part include a new backlight? If he swapped the screens without adding a new backlight he might not solved the real problem.

Comment: It's not that NIkon USA *can't* fix it. It's that Nikon USA *won't* fix it. For what it's worth, Canon USA will usually repair a non-USA camera or lens, assuming it is a repairable defect that they would also do for a "US" body or lens, and will sometimes even do it under warranty, though there is no guarantee regarding the warranty.

Comment: @Arjihad The backlight is usually inside the same unit as the screen itself. It may be a power supply issue from the main PC board to the backlight, which would probably be carried on a separate circuit than the data going to the screen.

Comment: I could also imagine a broken flex cable.